# Check if all the responses are false

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if all the statements being returned are false. Take a look at the following code:

```
angular.forEach($scope.preferencesAccount, function(account){
    //console.log(account);
    if (typeof account === 'object') {
        var allStatuses = [];  
        angular.forEach(account, function(alertStatus){
            console.log(alertStatus.enabled);
        })                        
    }                    
})
```

alertstatus.enabled returns the following:
[image]

I want to check if all the values returned are false so I can perform something. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just iterate over your `enabled` and check whether the length is the same as your alertStatuses:

```
angular.forEach($scope.preferencesAccount, function(account){
    //console.log(account);
    if (typeof account === 'object') {
        var allStatuses = [];  
        var falseCounter = 0;
        angular.forEach(account, function(alertStatus){
            console.log(alertStatus.enabled);
            if(!alertStatus.enabled)
                 falseCounter++;

        })    
        if(falseCounter === account.length)
        {
            // handle when all are false
        }                    
    }                    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all your responses in an Array, use this:

```
if( responses.every(function( response ) { return !response }) ) {
    // ...
}
```

If you're doing this for your own personal purposes and don't care about compatibility with other browsers, you can use this shortcut (**but don't use it if you're writing this for other people**)

Assuming you get all the responses into an array, you can check it like this...

```
if( responses.every( response => !response ) ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't believe arrow functions are implemented in IE yet either - best to stick with the second one for now unless you're transpiling your code.

Comment: That's probably true. Editing

Answer (score -1):

you can use Array.every

```
[false, false, false].every(function (x) {
    return !x;
});
```

This will return true